# find a dialog in ida using resource hacker

Tags: ida, patch-reversing, pe-resources

I am having difficulties finding the dialog reference in IDA.
e.g. i can trace a dialog in "resource Hacker" or "PE Explorer" which looks like this:

```
5035 DIALOG 0, 0, 295, 163
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP
CAPTION ""
LANGUAGE LANG_DANISH, 0x1
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
{
   CONTROL "", -1, STATIC, SS_BLACKFRAME | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 295, 163 
   CONTROL "Static", 1526, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP, 129, 121, 68, 16 
   CONTROL "Static", 1527, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_GROUP, 199, 123, 93, 14 
   CONTROL 551, -1, STATIC, SS_BITMAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 295, 163 
   CONTROL "Progress1", 1232, "msctls_progress32", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 0, 138, 295, 14 
   CONTROL "Number of trials left:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP, 2, 154, 63, 8 
   CONTROL "15", 1519, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP, 65, 154, 9, 8 
}
```

How, or what should i look for in IDA in order to find where it is being referenced?

Answer (score -1):

Search for a call to FindResource with 5035(0x13AB) as lpName argument

Comment: This answer could be significantly improved

Comment: Nope, the answer is precisely covering all the aspects of the question.

Comment: I tend to disagree. More specifically: how confident are you there's a call to `FindResource` and what alternatives are there? What's the significance of `0x13AB`, how you got that value and what's it's relation with `lpName`?

Comment: Totally agree with @NirIzr. This answer makes a whole lot of assumptions and should at the very least mention them explicitly. For example it's well possible to use `DialogBoxIndirect()` and `DialogBox()` and their variants without having to resort `FindResource()`. And while internally something like `FindResource()` will be employed to look up the resource, this call won't happen from that executable but somewhere in the opaque part of the call path. Also the internal version will likely not be `FindResource()` but something like `LdrFindResource_U()` ...

Comment: You still need FindResource to use DialogBoxIndirect and DialogBox. And LdrFindResource_U is totally out of scope.